# Ubuntu - vagrant access from another computer

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtualbox

I have recently learned how to setup a virtual machine using vagrant (virtualbox), and I know how to access it from a web browser via the local adress such as `192.168.x.x:9292` since 9292 is the default gate. But I would like to access the server from another computer locally.

My question is if I could access it via cmd as I connect to it on my own with the command `vagrant ssh` but from another computer via a command like `vagrant ssh 192.168.x.x`?

As far as I understand you have to use external programs or setup something inside the vagrant environment? Is there a simple way to access the server or is it password protected? If I setup a website I can access that for example from another local machine but can I access files on the server (from another computer)?

Comment: you need to run ssh command directly against the VM IP and port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to connect to another computer locally by entering the vagrant environment, `vagrant up` --> `vagrant ssh`. And connected to another computer by typing in `ssh vagrant@192.168.x.x` where 192.168.x.x is the local address to the computer. The vagrant asks for a password and you type in the default password which I believe is vagrant and then you are connected to the other vagrant instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have virtualbox provider for Vagrant you can achieve this by doing bridging the VBox network interface with Host.

Use this in Vagratfile (for public/private)

**For Public**

```
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network",
    use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
end
```

**For Private**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
end
```

above code will create IP in the range of Host network and using this you can access the file server from another machine.

Comment: This line `use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true` should use an equals sign `use_dhcp_assigned_default_route = true`, at least in vagrant version 2.0.2. When I tried using a colon I got a syntax error.